# Connecting Smart Watch to Raspberry Pi

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, sony-smartwatch

I am developing project on Raspberry Pi and I need to add feature of measuring heart rate. I want to use Smart Watch to do that but I do not know which smart watch provide environment which allows me to implement wireless communication between watch and Raspberry (Raspbian OS) easily. Thank you in advance for each answer.

Comment: Which version of Sony SmartWatch you are going to use?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any smart-watch allows direct connection between Raspberry Pi and smart-watch. It is not recommended on android developer site to open lower level sockets as well. You can send smart-watch's sensor data to Phone and then send it to Raspberry Pi.